# Print specific fields from aws routetables

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I'm trying to print specific fields of aws routetables from all existing routetables which has VPC peering connections(pcx)

```
#!/bin/bash
export PS4='${LINENO}:'

export AWS_REGION=us-east-1

echo "AccountID," "RouteTableName," "RouteTableId," "SubnetName," "SubnetId," 
"Target," "SubnetCidrBlock," "DestinationCidrBlock," "Status," >>nonprod.csv
#set -x

for tables in nonprod
do
    aws ec2 describe-route-tables --region us-east-1 > RoutetablesOld.txt
    aws ec2 describe-subnets --region us-east-1 > SubnetsOld.txt
    declare -i numroutetable
    declare -a numsubnets
    numsubnets=$(jq ".Subnets|length" SubnetsOld.txt)
    numroutetable=$(jq -r '.RouteTables|length' RoutetablesOld.txt)


    for ((i=0;i<$numroutetable;i++))
    do
        declare -i numroutes
        numroutes=$(jq ".RouteTables[$i].Routes|length" RoutetablesOld.txt)
        for ((k=0;k<$numroutes;k++))
        do
            declare -i numassociations
            numassociations=$(jq ".RouteTables[$i].Associations|length" 
            RoutetablesOld.txt)
        for ((j=0;j<$numassociations;j++))
        do

            for ((a=0;a<$numsubnets;a++))
            do

                SubnetId=$(jq -r ".RouteTables[$i].Associations[$j].SubnetId" 
                RoutetablesOld.txt)
                RouteTableId=$(jq -r 
                ".RouteTables[$i].Associations[$j].RouteTableId" 
                RoutetablesOld.txt)
                RouteTableName=$(jq -r ".RouteTables[$i] |(.Tags[] | 
                select(.Key==\"Name\") | .Value)" RoutetablesOld.txt)
                DestinationCidrBlock=$(jq -r 
                ".RouteTables[$i].Routes[$k].DestinationCidrBlock" 
                RoutetablesOld.txt)
                VpcPeeringConnectionId=$(jq -r 
".RouteTables[$i].Routes[$k].VpcPeeringConnectionId" RoutetablesOld.txt)
                TransitGatewayId=$(jq -r 
".RouteTables[$i].Routes[$k].TransitGatewayId" RoutetablesOld.txt)
                Subnet=$(jq -r ".Subnets[$a].SubnetId" SubnetsOld.txt)
                SubnetCidrBlock=$(jq -r ".Subnets[$a].CidrBlock" 
 SubnetsOld.txt)
                SubnetName=$(jq -r ".Subnets[$a] |(.Tags[] | 
 select(.Key==\"Name\") | .Value)" SubnetsOld.txt)
                if [ "${VpcPeeringConnectionId}" != "null" ] && [ 
 "${SubnetId}" == "${Subnet}" ]; then
                    echo "\"Nonprod\"," "\"$RouteTableName\"," 
 "\"$RouteTableId\"," "\"$SubnetName\"," "\"$SubnetId\"," 
 "\"$VpcPeeringConnectionId\"," "\"$SubnetCidrBlock\"," 
 "\"$DestinationCidrBlock\"," "Pre-Rollout">>nonprod.csv
                elif [ "${TransitGatewayId}" != "null" ] && [ "${SubnetId}" 
 == "${Subnet}" ]; then
                    echo "\"Nonprod\"," "\"$RouteTableName\"," 
 "\"$RouteTableId\"," "\"$SubnetName\"," "\"$SubnetId\"," 
 "\"$TransitGatewayId\"," "\"$SubnetCidrBlock\"," 
 "\"$DestinationCidrBlock\"," "Pass">>nonprod.csv
                else
                    echo "Target cidrs are neither pcx nor tgw"
                fi
                continue
            done
        done
    done
  done
done
```

My resultant output file will contain below fields

AccountID, RouteTableName, RouteTableId, SubnetName, SubnetId, Target, SubnetCidrBlock, DestinationCidrBlock, Status

I'm trying to print all pcx routes from existing routetables and there associated subnets with subnet cidr block.`enter code here`

However, my output prints only pcx from two route tables and script keeps on running. output file has only entries from two routetables. for only one subnet.

Comment: @Cyrus  Updated the code with white spaces

Comment: `~~~` is easier to mark code.

Comment: This line `for tables in nonprod` results in the outer loop being run exactly once with the variable `$tables` being set to the literal string "nonprod" and then that variable is never used. You should use meaningful variable names in place of `a`, `i`, `j` and `k`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson After updating this question. I realised outer loop is not required. I did run script without the outerloop and still get same result

Comment: You're declaring `numsubnets` as an array and populating it with a string (non-array) which may be numeric (but I can't tell) from a `jq` command - then in a `for` statement you're using it as an integer. By the way, I don't recommend using `declare -i`.